# customize argparse with -help support

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to enable -help option to user. I found couple of example but did not any concrete direction.

```
import argparse
import os
import sys

def parse_args(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-upf", dest="upf", help="provide upf file full path")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def main(argv):
    args = parse_args(argv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

python test.py -help

"error: argument -h/--help: ignored explicit argument 'elp'

Comment: use `python test.py -h` or `python test.py --help`

Comment: This is the difference between short and long options, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21852/single-dashes-for-single-character-options-but-double-dashes-for-words

Comment: yes I need to provide -help support. is it possible to provide such option

Comment: You need to use double dashes for long options (e.g. `--help`) and a single dash for short options (e.g. `-h`)

Comment: yes... people is using -help option (perl user) so looking same interface for python.. so i am exploring -help if we can support

Comment: I don't think so because that would break the possibility to combine multiple short options into one: if the program defines `-h`, `-e`, `-l` and `-p` as flags then you can combine them as `-help`, thus setting all of them at once. That's why there's a distinction between short and long options.

Comment: in other words, Python follows the UNIX convention for command line arguments but other programs don't. Plenty of examples for either way. But even Perl follow it: https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long#Command-Line-Options,-an-Introduction

Comment: small correction: it's a GNU convention